# How can I replace the button in Mission Control that adds a new virtual desktop (+) when the dock is positioned on the right side?

Tags: macos, terminal, dock, window-manager, mission-control

I use MacBook Pro M3 with macOS  Sonoma 14.4.

[image]

The button in Mission Control that adds a new virtual desktop (+) generally located аt right side, when the dock orientation down or left. That is more convenient than the left button location.
Is there a command in the terminal to move it to the other side of the display?

*I use macbook pro m3 pro Sonoma 14.4*

Comment: Fixed?  What exactly is broken?

Comment: I’m gonna edit this @Allan since it says from and to the unasked question in words was how to move the control location. Let’s see if that is correct.